# Using richtextbox instead of File.WriteBytes

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code now:

```
Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\desktop\image.png")
File.WriteAllBytes("D:\desktop\file.txt", data)
```

Instead of File.WriteAllBytes (writing to a file) I want to write those bytes to a richtextbox, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use like the following

```
    Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("K:\sample.txt")
    ritchText.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)
```

If you give the input as image file then you will get only `Unicode characters`. if you give `textfile` like the above then will give the exact content of the input file.

Comment: This retuns an other result  then when I write a file